# In Mathematica. When using images as vertices in GraphPlot, how do I prevent images from overlapping?

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I am using `GraphPlot` to draw directed graphs with roughly a 100 vertices. I am replacing each vertex with a small rectangular or square image by defining the VertexRenderingFunction. The images often overlap. Is there a way to get Mathematica to space the vertices further apart to prevent them from overlapping?

I have tried the various obvious options for 'Method' ("SpringElectricalEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", "HighDimensionalEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", "RandomEmbedding", "LinearEmbedding").

```
trans = {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 1,
8 -> 1, 9 -> 1, 10 -> 1, 11 -> 1, 12 -> 1, 13 -> 1, 14 -> 1, 
15 -> 1, 16 -> 1, 17 -> 1, 18 -> 13, 19 -> 1, 20 -> 13, 21 -> 13, 
22 -> 70, 23 -> 1, 24 -> 1, 25 -> 1, 26 -> 1, 27 -> 13, 28 -> 13, 
29 -> 1, 30 -> 13, 31 -> 13, 32 -> 1, 33 -> 19, 34 -> 70, 35 -> 70,
36 -> 1, 37 -> 1, 38 -> 1, 39 -> 39, 40 -> 13, 41 -> 2, 42 -> 13, 
43 -> 1, 44 -> 2, 45 -> 1, 46 -> 52, 47 -> 2, 48 -> 68, 49 -> 49, 
50 -> 19, 51 -> 78, 52 -> 1, 53 -> 1, 54 -> 39, 55 -> 13, 56 -> 56,
57 -> 13, 58 -> 13, 59 -> 1, 60 -> 36, 61 -> 1, 62 -> 52, 63 -> 2,
6 4 -> 68, 65 -> 19, 66 -> 56, 67 -> 4, 68 -> 76, 69 -> 19, 
70 -> 78, 71 -> 1, 72 -> 39, 73 -> 52, 74 -> 56, 75 -> 23, 
76 -> 76, 77 -> 56, 78 -> 78};

image = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};

GraphPlot[trans, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True,
VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
ArrayPlot[image, ImageSize -> 15, Mesh -> True], #1] &)]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Why don't you include the code that you used (or some sampling of it) so we can examine the issue you are having .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am looking into some of the suggestions you have made. I have added an example which may help to clarify my question.

Comment: Are you planning to have identical images for each of the vertices? Or will some vertices look different? (I have a reason for asking).

Comment: Each vertex has a different image, each representing a state of a 2x5 cellular automata. I have code that generates a list of binary matrices, each reperesenting one of the images. The Arrayplot function then converts the matrix to an image which I can include in the graph.

Answer (score 3):

Edit [I started over, based on the example you gave]:

Using your `trans` and `image` you could try:

```
p = ArrayPlot[image, ImageSize -> 35, Mesh -> True];

Graph[trans, DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabels -> Placed[p, Tooltip], 
  ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The images will appear in tooltips when you mouse over each vertex. You could use different images for different vertex labels if you wish; just use a list of rules.

The picture below shows what it looks like (without the tooltips).
Click on [link](http://screencast.com/t/Gnobw6mlAI) to see how it works with tooltips.

[image: graph]

Comment: Thats a pretty neat way to do it! Haven't used tooltips before. But I am printing out the images to put into my thesis, would like to be able to see all the images at once.

Comment: Yes, tooltips won't appear on paper. So it looks like your graph may need to be drawn a bit larger than you originally envisioned. There is no reason, a priori, why you can't use a full page to display a figure with caption, right?  At that scale your current solution, via `GraphPlot` should work. If I needed even more control over the rendering, I'd use OmniGraffle Pro (for a Mac) or Visio. For a one-off solution, this will work.  If you have multiple figures with 100 vertices, the amount of work will be prohibitive.

Comment: I have a number of these type of graphs. A large portion I have already edited using ipe, but it is quite time consuming. I was hoping there is a generic solution. A small problem when scaling the figures is that when resizing the figures by dragging a corner of the image, the size of the arrows on the directed edges scale to and one or two images may still overlap requiring some manual editing (which is already better), but would be nice to have a perfect solution where everything happens more or less automatically. Thanks for all your input so far! I have learned a couple new tricks.